# roslaunch - namespace substitution within group tags

Tags: ros, roslaunch, xml, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a multiple robot application and am trying to develop a clean launch file.  I have multiple blocks of XML in my launch file that look like...

```
<group ns="r1">
  <include file="$(find mypack)/launch/robot.launch">
    <arg name="namespace" value="r1" /> 
  </include>
</group>
```

I need to pass the namespace to the robot.launch file explicitly (long story).  I don't like it that I have to input the "r1" value twice.  It would be more pleasing if I could use substitution to assign a value to the namespace argument so that I only had to define the "r1" value once.  Something like...

```
<group ns="r1">
  <include file="$(find mypack)/launch/robot.launch">
    <arg name="namespace" value="$(arg ns)" /> 
  </include>
</group>
```

I tried to have an argument before the group tag that I reassigned each time, but that caused errors. Evidently I can't reassign arguments.

Any creative thoughts much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229185/roslaunch---namespace-substitution-within-group-tags/) by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, what should work is the following:

- have your `robot.launch` as it is
- a `robot_ns.launch` with the following in it:

  ```
    <arg name="my_ns"/>
    <group ns="$(arg my_ns)">
          <include file="$(find mypack)/launch/robot.launch">
            <arg name="namespace" value="$(arg my_ns)" /> 
        </include>
    </group>
  ```
- and then, in the top-level launch file, do the following:

  ```
    <include file="$(find mypack)/launch/robot_ns.launch">
        <arg name="my_ns" value="r1" /> 
    </include>

    <include file="$(find mypack)/launch/robot_ns.launch">
        <arg name="my_ns" value="r2" /> 
    </include>
  ```

You then don't reassign arguments (which you actually cannot) and you only have to write the namespaces out once.

I guess you could also have this in just one launch file, if your `robot.launch` could handle an empty `namespace` argument with the `group` tags correctly.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1